# T-SQL Group Check

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have three tables - Table_1, Table_2 and Table_3. Here's what each looks like:

**Table_1**

```
   ID  | TicketID | Rule  
---------------------------
    1  |    101   | NULL
```

**Table_2**

```
    TicketID | Location
---------------------------  
       101   | A
       101   | B
```

**Table_3**

```
Location | Rule
--------------------
    A    |  R1
    B    |  R1
    A    |  R2
    B    |  R2
    C    |  R2
```

My goal is to populate the Rule column in Table_1 (which should be a select distinct of the Rule column in Table_3). The process should be:

- Take the TicketID from Table_1. Join Table_1 to Table_2 on TicketID and get the Locations associated with that ticket.
- Look up Table_3 and check what Rule needs to be applied. The check needs to be at the group level. For instance, in this example, Ticket 101 has locations A,B. Table_3 has A,B against Rule R1 but also has A,B,C against Rule R2. The correct rule should be R1 as Ticket 101 has no allocation for location C. Hope this make sense. What would be the easiest way of achieving this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried so far? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: What should happen for a ticket that only has one location (say, `A`)? What should happen for a ticket that has *more* locations (say, `A, B, C, D`)?

Comment: Do you want to _insert_ into the first table, or _update_ the first table?  And please show your desired output.

Comment: Also, is there any possibility the `R3` also just has rows for `A` and `B` in table 3? If so, which rule should be selected?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If a ticket has one location A, then the output should be something like 'Multiple'. In reality, this shouldn't happen. If it has A,B,C,D and that combination is not available in Table_3 then it goes to another table to do the same check but based on different attributes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Should be an insert.

Comment: Tricky.. Are the locations in table_2 and table_3 always going to be in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code. Its working fine in SQL server 2012.

```
DECLARE @table_1 TABLE
(ID int, TicketID int, [Rule] Varchar(10))

DECLARE @table_2 TABLE
(TicketID int, Location Varchar(10))

DECLARE @table_3 TABLE
(Location Varchar(10),[Rule] Varchar(10))

INSERT @table_1
(ID,TicketID,[Rule])
VALUES
(1,101,NULL)

INSERT @table_2
(TicketID,Location)
VALUES
(101,'A'),
(101,'B')

INSERT @table_3
(Location,[Rule])
VALUES
('A','R1'),
('B','R1'),
('A','R2'),
('B','R2'),
('C','R2')

SELECT DISTINCT [RULE] FROM @table_3 t3 WHERE t3.Location IN
(SELECT t2.Location FROM @table_2 t2 INNER JOIN @table_1 t1 ON t1.TicketID = t2.TicketID)
AND [RULE] NOT IN 
(SELECT t.[RULE] FROM @table_3 t WHERE t.Location NOT IN 
(SELECT t2.Location FROM @table_2 t2 INNER JOIN @table_1 t1 ON t1.TicketID = t2.TicketID))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's good but I've just changed @table_2 to now include a third record (101,'C') and it's now returning R1 and R2 whereas I just need R2?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS..

```
SELECT t1.TicketID
,t2.[Rule]
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t2.TicketID,[Rule]
FROM @table_3 t3 INNER JOIN 
     @table_2 t2 ON t2.Location = t3.Location) t2
INNER JOIN @table_1 t1 ON t2.TicketID = t1.TicketID
```

Use this select statement with the above declared table variable

Answer (score 0):

```
--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344006/t-sql-group-check
set nocount on
drop table #temp
DECLARE @table_1 TABLE
(ID int, TicketID int, [Rule] Varchar(10))

DECLARE @table_2 TABLE
(TicketID int, Location Varchar(10),obs int)

DECLARE @table_3 TABLE
(Location Varchar(10),[Rule] Varchar(10), obs int)

INSERT @table_1
(ID,TicketID,[Rule])
VALUES
(1,101,NULL)

INSERT @table_2
(TicketID,Location)
VALUES
(101,'A'),
(101,'B'),
--(101,'C')
(102,'A'),
(102,'B'),
(102,'C'),
(102,'S')

INSERT @table_3
(Location,[Rule])
VALUES
('A','R1'),
('B','R1'),
('A','R2'),
('B','R2'),
('C','R2'),
('S','R2')

declare @table_4 table (src varchar(2), id varchar(3), obs int)
insert into @table_4
select  't2', [ticketid], count(*) from @table_2 group by [ticketid]

Insert into @table_4
select  't3',[rule], count(*) from @table_3 group by [rule]

update  @table_2
set     obs = t4.obs
from    @table_2 t2
join    @table_4 t4 on t4.id = t2.ticketid
where   t4.src = 't2' 

update  @table_3
set     obs = t4.obs
from    @table_3 t3
join    @table_4 t4 on  rtrim(t4.id) = rtrim(t3.[rule])
where   t4.src = 't3'

select  t2.ticketid,t2.location as t2location,t2.obs as t2obs,t3.location as t3location,t3.[Rule],t3.obs as t3obs
into    #temp
from    @table_2 t2
full    join    @table_3 t3 on t3.location = t2.location

delete  #temp
where   [rule] in (select [rule] from #temp where ticketid is null)     

--select  t.*
--from  #temp t

select  distinct ticketid,[rule]
from    #temp
where   t2location = t3location and t2obs = t3obs
```

Comment: Not sexy and probably not optimal but it seems to work. The trick seems to be understanding how many locations are related to tickets in table 2 and rule in table 3 then "forgetting" all rule/locations where any rule/location in a rule returns a null value when joined to table 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
SELECT DISTINCT [RULE] FROM Table_3 t3 WHERE t3.Location IN
(SELECT t2.Location FROM Table_2 t2 INNER JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.TicketID = t2.TicketID)
AND [RULE] NOT IN 
(SELECT t.[RULE] FROM Table_3 t WHERE t.Location NOT IN 
(SELECT t2.Location FROM Table_2 t2 INNER JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.TicketID = t2.TicketID))
```